# Make a node server not cache files

Tags: node.js, build, hot-reload

I set up a repository for 3rd parties to create plugins in our website. Essentially, I based our repo off of Markus Oberlehner's guide here: https://github.com/maoberlehner/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http.

I only included the files and folders necessary for compiling vue components into js files. I did not include any of his code that is dedicated to including these external js files in another project.

A user can easily compile a vue component into a js file with the following command.

```
npx vue-cli-service build --target lib --formats umd-min --no-clean --dest server/com
ponents/SendNotification --name "SendNotification" server/components/SendNotification
/SendNotification.vue
```

and serve this component by executing `node server/index.js`.

This .js file is then available in a browser at:

> http://localhost:8200/SendNotification/SendNotification.umd.min.js

However, say the user wants to make a change to their component and recompiles the .js file, this change does not appear in the browser. The change only appears if I reload the browser tab. I think this means that the site is caching the files and we need to disable this.

I have searched for a straightforward tutorial and docs on how to disable the caching and have not been able to get this working.

Our directory structure:

```
- .git
- package.json
- package-lock.json
- README.md
- node_modules
- server
 -- index.js
 -- components
 --- SendNotification
 ---- SendNotification.vue
 ---- SendNotification.umd.min.js
 ---- SendNotification.umd.min.js.map
```

package.json contents:

```
 {
  "name": "precompiling-vue-components",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Bob Smith",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.12.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.12.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "node-sass-magic-importer": "^5.3.2",
    "reset-css": "^4.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
  }
}
```

index.js contents:

const express = require(`express`);
const path = require(`path`);

```
const PORT = 8200;

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, `components`), {
  maxAge: `365d`,
}));

app.listen(PORT);

// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
console.log(`Listening on: http://localhost:${PORT}`);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a caching issue. The client loads the page from the server when it loads, and unless you have some communication from the loaded page to the server, it knows nothing further about the server-side state.

You need to hotreload the client page.

The requires something like [browser-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync), or your own [socket.io](https://socket.io/) implementation to inform the client that the page has updated.

Remember that the client is decoupled from the server, and has no knowledge of what happens on the server unless the user reloads the page, the client code polls the server for changes, or the server communicates a change to the client over some form of subscription over a websocket.

Comment: Our directory structure is different from the typical app described by browser-sync implementation docs. Can we implement browser-sync in our current app simply by modifying index.js?

Comment: Yes, you need to use socket.io to create a websocket in the client and connect to a socket server in your express app, or else write a setInterval in the client code to poll your server to get a hash or some other signal about changes.